# Given the dataset, how to select the learning algorithm?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I've to build an ML model to classify sentences into different categories. I have a dataset with 2 columns (sentence and label) and 350 rows i.e. with shape (350, 2). To convert the sentences into numeric representation I've used TfIdf vectorization, and so the transformed dataset now has 452 columns (451 columns were obtained using TfIdf, and 1 is the label) i.e. with shape (350, 452). More generally speaking, I have a dataset with a lot more features than training samples. In such a scenario what's the best classification algorithm to use? Logistic Regression, SVM (again what kernel?), neural networks (again which architecture?), naive Bayes or is there any other algorithm?

How about if I get more training samples in the future (but the number of columns doesn't increase much), say with a shape (10000, 750)?

**Edit**: The sentences are actually narrations from bank statements. I have around 10 to 15 labels, all of which I have labelled manually. Eg. Tax, Bank Charges, Loan etc. In future I do plan to get more statements and I will be labelling them as well. I believe I may end up having around 20 labels at most.

Answer (score 0):

With such a small training set, I think you would only get any reasonable results by getting some pre-trained language model such as GPT-2 and fine tune to your problem. That probably is still true even for a larger dataset, a neural net would probably still do best even if you train your own from scratch. Btw, how many labels do you have? What kind of labels are those?

Comment: I have added info about labels in Edit section

Comment: Luckily that is not a lot o labels, i think that using a pre trained language model would still give you the best results. One downside is that GPT-2 is pretty big, and it may take a lot of time and resources to classify sentences.

Comment: Thanks, but for my purpose this is too much complex